# Get Wordpress JSON Data

Tags: php, json, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using the code below to get data on posts that are Woocommerce products in my Worpdress website

```
$args = array( 'post_type' => 'product', 'posts_per_page' => 100, 'product_cat' => 'Tools' );
$loop = new WP_Query( $args );
echo $loop->get_posts();
wp_reset_query();
```

This works. But I also want to get post meta for each product so that I can get attributes such as price.

I want to print this data in json format using `json_encode( $loop->get_posts())`, so I must do this **without a loop** else invalid json would be returned.

How do I combine the data from `get_posts()` and `get_post_meta()`, so that I can encode it as one json object to pull data from?

Comment: why dont you create a function in `functions.php` and make the json by hand?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "make the json by hand"

Answer (score 0):

```
$query = new WP_Query($args);
echo "var json =". json_encode($query->get_posts());
wp_reset_query();
```